# favicon-<name> on Stack Exchange sites... icons... need relation between <name> and something, like site number or site name

Tags: discussion, api

I am making a client for Stack Overflow... I want to show the icons for Stack Exchange network/sites... found some CSS that contains something like:

```
.favicon-english {
  background-position: 0 -2196px
}

.favicon-englishmeta {
  background-position: 0 -2214px
}

.favicon-es {
  background-position: 0 -2232px
}
```

But it seems the correlation between the `favicon-<name>` is done serverside? Does anyone know or found any code that has the `<name>` and something from the site, like the number or the name? I'm trying to find any JavaScript code that has it, but I couldn't find it...

Comment: have the image for it, but not the name/id or name/site name relation

Comment: The offsets are to the CSS sprite that holds all images; since that sprite is generated together with the CSS, the numbers are generated at that time and are not meant for 3rd-party use. Better to use the individual images served by the API.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, thanks, will use that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to mess around with CSS files, separate icons are already available in the API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites

Example for Stack Overflow:

```js
"high_resolution_icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png",
"favicon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico",
"icon_url": "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
```

Comment: ha... didn't saw that method in the api... thanks! anyway would be nice to be able to use the "only one image"... but that will work, thanks